# IE9: store.find is failing

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I can't seem to fetch new data in Internet Explorer 9. For the purpose of an example I test the store this way:

`App.__container__.lookup('store:main').find('style')`

The only error I receive is the following:

`SCRIPT5022: Error: Assertion Failed: [object Object]`

Does Ember-data works out of the box (without polyfills, ...) in Internet Explorer 9?

versions:

- Ember:  1.9.1
- Ember-data:  1.0.0-beta.12

Comment: My guess is you'd need a simple ES5 shim but w/out a little more info it's hard to tell for sure (also ED is up to beta 16+ now I think so that might be worth a look). If you trap the error in IE9's dev tools -can you get a line # or legit stacktrace to nail down the real issue inside ember-data?

Comment: This is the great thing about Internet Explorer 9, it only shows me an error icon but no message or possibility to see a stacktrace. That is why I  was wondering Ember-data needs some specific shim or polyfill to work in Internet Explorer. I also tried adding an ES5 shim, but this did not make any difference.

Comment: Do you get this same error w/ IE8 or no? I found using virtualbox and IE8 that I could see the line # (in development mode) and then I could request that same file locally (on my dev machine) w/ chrome and pull up the vendor.js or whatever js file to see the line of code that died. Is this an option /any other info you can get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. When doing an AJAX request with jQuery, this normally happens through the XMLHttpRequest object.

On IE8-9, this object is not present, instead it uses XDomainRequest. The simplest fix for this is adding: https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest.

Answer (score 0):

ember-data works out of the box with IE8+.  According to [this issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2969#issuecomment-88739616):

> We've been supporting IE8 with our platform (built on Ember) for a
>   while now. Things I know:
>
> - shim/sham is not needed, it's polyfilled by Ember and Ember-Data.
> - You will need it if you want additional things like .bind() on a function, then you must prepend it to the vendor file (using Brocfile)
>     and we only include the shim for that purpose, not the sham

Answer (score 0):

## Solution Synthesis

***Reason :***

On IE8-9, this object is not present, instead it uses XDomainRequest.

***Solution :***

The issue is solved. When using an AJAX request with jQuery. Normally this is done through the XMLHttpRequest object. A simple fix would be using the Open-Source [jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest)

***Code :*** Adding :

jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest.js

```
/*!
 * jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest - v1.0.4 - 2015-03-05
 * https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest
 * Copyright (c) 2015 Jason Moon (@JSONMOON)
 * Licensed MIT (/blob/master/LICENSE.txt)
 */
(function(factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as anonymous module.
    define(['jquery'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // CommonJS
    module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
  } else {
    // Browser globals.
    factory(jQuery);
  }
}(function($) {

// Only continue if we're on IE8/IE9 with jQuery 1.5+ (contains the ajaxTransport function)
if ($.support.cors || !$.ajaxTransport || !window.XDomainRequest) {
  return $;
}

var httpRegEx = /^(https?:)?\/\//i;
var getOrPostRegEx = /^get|post$/i;
var sameSchemeRegEx = new RegExp('^(\/\/|' + location.protocol + ')', 'i');

// ajaxTransport exists in jQuery 1.5+
$.ajaxTransport('* text html xml json', function(options, userOptions, jqXHR) {

  // Only continue if the request is: asynchronous, uses GET or POST method, has HTTP or HTTPS protocol, and has the same scheme as the calling page
  if (!options.crossDomain || !options.async || !getOrPostRegEx.test(options.type) || !httpRegEx.test(options.url) || !sameSchemeRegEx.test(options.url)) {
    return;
  }

  var xdr = null;

  return {
    send: function(headers, complete) {
      var postData = '';
      var userType = (userOptions.dataType || '').toLowerCase();

      xdr = new XDomainRequest();
      if (/^\d+$/.test(userOptions.timeout)) {
        xdr.timeout = userOptions.timeout;
      }

      xdr.ontimeout = function() {
        complete(500, 'timeout');
      };

      xdr.onload = function() {
        var allResponseHeaders = 'Content-Length: ' + xdr.responseText.length + '\r\nContent-Type: ' + xdr.contentType;
        var status = {
          code: 200,
          message: 'success'
        };
        var responses = {
          text: xdr.responseText
        };
        try {
          if (userType === 'html' || /text\/html/i.test(xdr.contentType)) {
            responses.html = xdr.responseText;
          } else if (userType === 'json' || (userType !== 'text' && /\/json/i.test(xdr.contentType))) {
            try {
              responses.json = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);
            } catch(e) {
              status.code = 500;
              status.message = 'parseerror';
              //throw 'Invalid JSON: ' + xdr.responseText;
            }
          } else if (userType === 'xml' || (userType !== 'text' && /\/xml/i.test(xdr.contentType))) {
            var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
            doc.async = false;
            try {
              doc.loadXML(xdr.responseText);
            } catch(e) {
              doc = undefined;
            }
            if (!doc || !doc.documentElement || doc.getElementsByTagName('parsererror').length) {
              status.code = 500;
              status.message = 'parseerror';
              throw 'Invalid XML: ' + xdr.responseText;
            }
            responses.xml = doc;
          }
        } catch(parseMessage) {
          throw parseMessage;
        } finally {
          complete(status.code, status.message, responses, allResponseHeaders);
        }
      };

      // set an empty handler for 'onprogress' so requests don't get aborted
      xdr.onprogress = function(){};
      xdr.onerror = function() {
        complete(500, 'error', {
          text: xdr.responseText
        });
      };

      if (userOptions.data) {
        postData = ($.type(userOptions.data) === 'string') ? userOptions.data : $.param(userOptions.data);
      }
      xdr.open(options.type, options.url);
      xdr.send(postData);
    },
    abort: function() {
      if (xdr) {
        xdr.abort();
      }
    }
  };
});

return $;

}));
```